# How do I increment a number entered by user input for each line

Tags: batch-file

I need to make the `id` in second line to increment by `1`.

For example :

```
user id = 12000
```

I need second line `id` number to be `12001`, third line `id` to be `12002`, like this up to `60` lines.

Any help?

### the code

```
SET /P _id= Please enter id:
set /P _name= Please enter output name:
streamlink --hls-segment-threads 10 "http://x.x.x.x:xxxx/video/master.m3u8?channelId=%_id%" 720p -l debug -o "%_name%_1.mkv"
streamlink --hls-segment-threads 10 "http://x.x.x.x:xxxx/video/master.m3u8?channelId=%_id%" 720p -l debug -o "%_name%_2.mkv"
streamlink --hls-segment-threads 10 "http://x.x.x.x:xxxx/video/master.m3u8?channelId=%_id%" 720p -l debug -o "%_name%_3.mkv"
```

Comment: `first line`, `second line`, and `third line`, are not valid commands, we require a [mcve], along with debugging information explaining what is happening with the code, which is not expected. Currently it appears as if you've not made any attempt at the task, and therefore your question is an off topic code request. Please open a Command Prompt window, type `set /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read through its usage information. Write your own code then [edit] your question such that it meets the requirements set out throughout the pages of [ask]. Thank you.

Comment: i know that i just mention  the line number in additional

Comment: I have removed the invalid strings from your provided code.

Answer (score 2):

There are two different counters. You can manage one with a `for /L` loop and the other one by incrementing a variable inside the loop:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /p _id= Please enter id:
set /p _name= Please enter output name:
set /a _id_end=_id+60
set line=0
for /l %%i in (%_id%,1,%_id_end%) do (
  set /a line+=1
  echo streamlink ... "... channelId=%%i" 720p ... -o "%_name%_!line!.mkv"
)
```

Comment: its works good 
but in the output file from line 2 its the same of line 3 and ask to overwrite it

File asrar_!line!.mkv already exists! Overwrite it? [y/N]   " this is the line 3 output need to overwrite the output of line 2

Comment: @MohamedSerag the code provided works for me.

Comment: Your error message literally says `File asrar_!line!.mkv already exists`? You forgot `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` (or have a typo in this command)

Comment: i realy can't understant this
its first time ti deal with batch files
and setlocal enabledelayedexpansion already written

Comment: @Mohamed: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028) for an explanation/demonstration of delayed expansion (I tried to keep it short and simple).